# How to randomly form pairs of integers from an array of integers in c?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have an array of integers and I want to form pairs based on the indexes (randomly)
for example:

If I have an array of 8 integers I'll for example have:

element at index 0 with element at index 4
and 2-3,1-5,6-7

it doesn't matter if the integers (not indexes) are duplicate.

Comment: Shuffle the array and take numbers in order from it. If you can't or don't want to change the array then make a parallel array of indices, shuffle that and use it to pull the numbers.

Comment: [How to shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle)

Answer (score 0):

My method:

Start with a bitfield with 1 bit per valid index. E.g. for an array of 20 integers you'd want a bitfield with 20 bits. Clear all the bits in the bitfield.

Have a loop to generate enough "random index candidates" in the range from 0 to `n`, where `n` starts as the highest valid index but is decremented each time through the loop. E.g. for an array of 20 integers it might be like:

```
    for(int n = 19; n >= 0; n--) {
```

Inside the loop:

1. Get a "random index candidate" from the random number generator with a range from 0 to `n`.
2. Set `first_bit` to zero.
3. Count the number of set bits in the bitfield between `first_bit` and "random index candidate" (inclusively). If the count of set bits is non-zero; do `first_bit = random_index_candidate + 1` and add the count of set bits to "random index candidate", then repeat step 3 (until the count of set bits is zero).
4. Set the bit in the bitfield corresponding to the final "random index candidate". The "random index candidate" is now a "selected random index" (it's a part of the next pair of indices).

Notes:

- This method preserves the distribution of random numbers. E.g. if "`get_random_integer(n);`" has perfect distribution, then the "pairs of random indices" will have perfect distribution.
- The generated indices don't need to be stored. E.g. after a candidate becomes selected (step 4) you could do something like "`if(n&1 != 0) (temp = selected_index; } else { process_pair(temp, selected_index); }`"
- Some modern CPUs have instructions to count the number of set bits (e.g. the `popcnt` instruction on 80x86) that can be used to increase the speed of step 3
- For extremely large arrays, you could split the bitfield into multiple zones, keep track of "number of set bits in each zone", and use that to increase the speed of step 3. E.g. if the original array has 2 million elements then you could have 489 groups with 4096 bits per group.
- Because the bitfield is much smaller than an array of integers, this method is more "cache friendly" than shuffling an array of integers.

Comment: Pseudocode without explanation is not a good answer, as it can be difficult to see the intent, especially for novice learners. And this code appears to be buggy. Suppose after, say, 15 selections, bits 0 to 9 happen to be set. Then we are selecting candidates in [0, 4]. Step 3 would have us count the number of bits set in positions up to the selected candidate position, so some subset of the bits in positions 0 to 4. This produces a number equal to the candidate plus one. Then we add that to the candidate, producing 2•candidate+1. That is at most 9, so it is one of the set bits…

Comment: … So step 4 tells us to increment the candidate and retry. It is unclear whether that means to retry starting at step 3 or step 4. If it is step 4, we increment until we find the first clear bit. This is not a random uniform selection from the remaining set bits, so it appears to generate a skewed distribution. If it is step 3, we end up testing 2•(candidate+1)+1 = 2•candidate+3, so we skipped 2*candidate+2, which could have been clear. Or maybe something else is meant, and the pseudocode is expressed unclearly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Hrm - you're right. The intent of steps 3 and 4 was to implement "find the Kth clear bit in the bitfield" (where K is the original candidate), which would've preserved the uniformity of the distribution. The problem is that simple addition (at the end of step 3) skips over an unknown number of clear bits (and breaks the "find then Kth clear bit"). Give me a few minutes to figure out the best way to reword it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Fixed (I hope) :-)

Comment: I am out of time now, so I may look at the update later. But answers should not just present either code or pseudocode that say “Do this with bits.” They should say “Here is a method to select from the remaining unselected items, with a random uniform distribution,” and perhaps explain why selecting items randomly in this way forms “random” pairs, and so on.

Comment: This is massively overengineered unless OP is working with millions of integers and has critical time requirements -- in which case there's a good chance that larger design considerations will affect the stipulation